Facebook Graph API not Returning Leads for Specific Ad but Visible in Ads Manager
I’m facing an issue where the Facebook Graph API is not returning lead data for a specific ad, even though the leads are visible in the Ads Manager.
Here’s what I’ve done:
I’m using the following endpoint to retrieve the leads:
GET /{ad_id}/leads?fields=id,created_time,field_data&limit=1000
The leads for other ads are returned correctly, but for one particular ad ("ad1 - Copy"), no leads are returned, even though I can clearly see them in the Facebook Ads Manager (65 leads in total).
I’ve made sure that my access token has the required permissions:
leads_retrieval
ads_read
ads_management
pages_manage_ads
I’ve also tried adding parameters like date_preset=maximum, but this doesn't help with retrieving the missing leads.
I've checked Stack Overflow and the Facebook Developer forums, but I haven't found a solution specific to this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and is there a known fix or workaround for this discrepancy between the Ads Manager and the API?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Environment:
API version: v20.0
Access token permissions: leads_retrieval, ads_read, ads_management
What I’ve Tried:
Refreshing the token and regenerating it with proper permissions.
Adding various query parameters (like limit and date_preset).
Expected Behavior:
The API should return all leads for "ad1 - Copy" just like it does for other ads.
